# Binarize a continuous feature with NaNs Python

Tags: pandas, binary, nan

I have a pandas dataframe of 4000 rows and 35 features, in which some of the continuous features contain missing values (NaNs). For example, one of them (with 46 missing values) has a very left-skewed distribution and I would like to binarize it by choosing a threshold of 1.5 below which I would like to set it as the class 0 and above or equal to 1.5 as the class 1.
Like: `X_original = [0.01,2.80,-1.74,1.34,1.55], X_bin = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1].`

I tried doing: `dataframe["bin"] = (dataframe["original"] > 1.5).astype(int)`.
However, I noticed that the missing values (NaNs) disappeared and they are encoded in the 0 class.

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: What do you want to do with missing values?

Comment: after I need to impute them with the rest of the features

Comment: impute them how?

Comment: using either the KNN Imputer or a LSTM

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge there is way to keep the missing values after a comparison, but you can do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

X_original = pd.Series([0.01,2.80,-1.74, np.nan,1.55])

X_bin = X_original > 1.5
X_bin[X_original.isna()] = np.NaN

print(X_bin)
```

**Output**

```
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    0.0
3    NaN
4    1.0
dtype: float64
```

To keep the column as Integer (and also nullable), do:

```
X_bin = X_bin.astype(pd.Int8Dtype())
print(X_bin)
```

**Output**

```
0       0
1       1
2       0
3    <NA>
4       1
dtype: Int8
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this issue that I found was to use list comprehension:

```
dataframe["Bin"] = [0 if el<1.5 else 1 if el >= 1.5 else np.NaN for el in dataframe["Original"]]
```

Then I convert the float numbers to objects except the `np.NaN`

```
dataframe["Bin"] = dataframe["Bin"].replace([0.0,1.0],["0","1"])
```